# Wordpress form cannot be received

Tags: wordpress

I recently building website using wordpress.

But the visitor figured out the form cannot be sent. When I check for the problem on the wordpress console, the console (workpress form) indicated an error: "1 configuration error detected in this tab panel".

[image: wordpress screenshot]

I've checked all my code and all brackets do exist. I am attaching the code below. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
<label> Name (required)
    [text* your-name-chi] </label>

<label> Nickname (required)
    [text* your-name-eng] </label>

<label> Sex
[select* sex include_blank "M" "F"] </label>

<label> Born Date
   [date* born-date] e.g: 1982-01-17</label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Contact Phone Number (required)
   [tel* mobile] </label>

<label> Phone Number ICOE (required)
   [tel* tel-urgent] </label>

<label> Address 
   [text address] </label>

<label> School Studying 
   [text school] </label>

<label> New/Old
[select* new_old include_blank "New" "Old"] </label>

<label> Class Type (required)
   [select* swimtype include_blank "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"] </label>

<label> Class Starting Date 
   [date startdate]  e.g: 2017-01-17 </label>

<label> Time(Hour preferred)
   [select startdatetime-1 include_blank "8"  "9"  "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21" ]  </label>
<label> Time(Minute preferred)
[select startdatetime-1-min include_blank  "00" "05"  "10" "15" "20"  "25"  "30"  "35"  "40"  "45"  "50"  "55"  "60"]
</label>

<label> Time(Hour - Second priority)
   [select startdatetime-2 include_blank "8"  "9"  "10"  "11"  "12"  "13"  "14"  "15"  "16"  "17"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21" ]  </label>
<label> Time(Minute - Second priority)
[select startdatetime-2-min include_blank  "00" "05"  "10" "15" "20"  "25"  "30"  "35"  "40"  "45"  "50"  "55"  "60"]
</label>

<label> On week (Preferred)
  [select week-1 include_blank "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thr" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"]</label>

<label> On week (Second priority)
   [select week-2 include_blank "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thr" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"] </label>

<label> Class Location (required)
   [select* swimpool include_blank "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "M" "N" "O"] </label>

<label> Where did you got the information of this course
   [select* adv include_blank "Facebook" "Leaflets "Online Search Engine" "Recommendations"] </label>

<label> Introducer (if any)
    [text recom] </label>
<label> Others
    [textarea your-message] </label>
<label> 
I agree with all the conditions [checkbox* agreement "Yes" "No"]</label>

<label> [submit "Send"] </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use  [checkbox] under 'label' tag.

Change your last few codes:-

```
  <label> 
      I agree with all the conditions</label> [checkbox* agreement "Yes" "No"]

 [submit "Send"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But my wordpress is still not functional normally, maybe it's due to other problems. I will check that out.

Comment: What problem you are facing now?

Comment: Maybe it's happening because of SMTP error (if an email is being not sent by your side to users). Please install Email Log plugin to your site and check wheater email is being successfully sent from your side or keeps getting failed?